# Pull/push status in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, sidekiq

I have a longer running task in the background, and how exactly would I let pull status from my background task or would it better somehow to communicate the task completion to my front end?

**Background :**

Basically my app uses third party service for processing data, so I want this external web service workload not to block all the incoming requests to my website, so I put this call inside a background job (I use sidekiq). And so when this task is done, I was thinking of sending a webhook to a certain controller which will notify the front end that the task is complete.

How can I do this? Is there a better solution for this?

**Update:**

My app is hosted on heroku

**Update II:**

I've done some research on the topic and I found out that I can create a seperate app on heroku which will handle this, found this example :

https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-websockets-chat-demo

This long running task will be run per user, on a website with a lot of traffic, is this a good idea?

Comment: It would be tricky to use HTML 5 socket-io, so I'd suggest you use Javascript (like jQuery for instance) and polling with a timer (`interval` function)

Comment: I think a more scalable solution that's also Heroku compatible is to have the background job write status to the user's database row or fast alternative (like a redis instance) and have the client poll for status on a timer.

Comment: Is this question about how to implement the backend part of it (starting the job, reporting statuses back to the application) or about the frontend part (how to notify the browser about status changes)?

Comment: @spickermann Question is about how the front-end receives something from back-end and responds to it. Doesn't matter what it receives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement this using a [pub/sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) system such as [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) or [Pusher](https://pusher.com/). The idea behind this is that you would publish the status of your long running job to a channel, which would then cause all subscribers of that channel to be notified of the status change.

For example, within your job runner you could notify Faye of a status change with something like:

```
client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/')
client.publish('/jobstatus', {id: jobid, status: 'in_progress'})
```

And then in your front end you can subscribe to that channel using javascript:

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/');

client.subscribe('/jobstatus', function(message) {
  alert('the status of job #' + message.jobid + ' changed to ' + message.status);
});
```

Using a pub/sub system in this way allows you to scale your realtime page events separately from your main app - you could run Faye on another server. You could also go for a hosted (and paid) solution like Pusher, and let them take care of scaling your infrastructure.

It's also worth mentioning that Faye uses the [bayeaux protocol](http://svn.cometd.org/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html), which means it will utilise websockets where it is available, and long-polling where it is not.

Comment: how do I configure channel name on faye? the default seems to be 'messages/new'

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow - the channel name is whatever you're subscribing to or publishing from, you don't have to preconfigure it.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

Comment: Faye looks much simpler than PubNub. Thanks for introducing me to it. Going to check it out now.

Answer (score 1):

We have this pattern and use two different approaches. In both cases background jobs are run with [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), but you could likely do something similar with [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

**Polling**

In the polling approach, we have a javascript object on the page that sets a timeout for polling with a URL passed to it from the rails HTML view.

This causes an Ajax ("script") call to the provided URL, which means Rails looks for the JS template. So we use that to respond with state and fire an event for the object to response to when available or not.

This is somewhat complicated and I wouldn't recommend it at this point.

**Sockets**

The better solution we found was to use WebSockets (with shims). In our case we use PubNub but there are numerous services to handle this. That keeps the polling/open-connection off your web server and is much more cost effective than running the servers needed to handle these connection.

You've stated you are looking for front-end solutions and you can handle all the front-end with PubNub's client JavaScript library.

Here's a rough idea of how we notify PubNub from the backend.

```
class BackgroundJob
  @queue = :some_queue

  def perform
    // Do some action
  end

  def after_perform
    publish some_state, client_channel
  end

  private

  def publish some_state, client_channel
    Pubnub.new(
        publish_key: Settings.pubnub.publish_key,
        subscribe_key: Settings.pubnub.subscribe_key,
        secret_key: Settings.pubnub.secret_key
    ).publish(
        channel: client_channel,
        message: some_state.to_json,
        http_sync: true
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach that I can think of is that you set a flag in your DB when the task is complete, and your front-end (view) sends an ajax request periodically to check the flag state in db. In case the flag is set, you take appropriate action in the view. Below are code samples:

Since you suggested that this long running task needs to run per user, so let's add a boolean to `users` table - `task_complete`. When you add the job to sidekiq, you can unset the flag:

```
# Sidekiq worker: app/workers/task.rb

class Task
include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    # Long running task code here, which executes per user
    user.task_complete = true
    user.save!
  end
end

# When adding the task to sidekiq queue
user = User.find(params[:id])
# flag would have been set to true by previous execution
# In case it is false, it means sidekiq already has a job entry. We don't need to add it again
if user.task_complete?
  Task.perform_async(user.id)
  user.task_complete = false
  user.save!
end
```

In the view you can periodically check whether the flag was set using ajax requests:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var complete = false;
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'task/status/<%= @user.id %>', 
    success: function(data) {
      // update the view based on ajax request response in case you need to
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete, and in case the global variable 'complete' is set to true, we don't need to fire this ajax request again - task is complete.
      if(!complete) {
      setTimeout(worker, 5000);  //in miliseconds
      }
    }
  });
})();
</script>

# status action which returns the status of task
# GET /task/status/:id
def status
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# status.js.erb - add view logic based on what you want to achieve, given whether the task is complete or not

<% if @user.task_complete? %>
  $('#success').show();
  complete = true;
<% else %>
  $('#processing').show();
<% end %>
```

You can set the timeout based on what the average execution time of your task is. Let's say your task takes 10 minutes on average, so their's no point in checking it at a 5sec frequency.

Also in case your task execution frequency is something complex (and not 1 per day), you may want to add a timestamp `task_completed_at` and base your logic on a combination of the flag and timestamp.

As for this part:
"This long running task will be run per user, on a website with a lot of traffic, is this a good idea?"

I don't see a problem with this approach, though architectural changes like executing jobs (sidekiq workers) on separate hardware will help. These are lightweight ajax calls, and some intelligence built into your javascript (like the global complete flag) will avoid the unnecessary requests. In case you have huge traffic, and DB reads/writes are a concern then you may want to store that flag directly into `redis` instead (since you already have it for sidekiq). I believe that will resolve your read/write concerns, and I don't see that it is going to cause problems. This is the simplest and cleanest approach I can think of, though you can try achieving the same via websockets, which are supported by most modern browsers (though can cause problems in older versions).

Comment: This is what I was referring to in my response with "Polling". And yes, it works. It's just a lot of code that you end up writing to keep things connected and a lot to maintain when you are trying to adapt new features. However, it works great and we still use it.